# Calculate number from CharArray

Tags: java, android, arrays, string, char

I have following code

```
 private static int getYear(char[] charArray)
{
    return (int)charArray[0] * 1000 + (int)charArray[1] * 100 + (int)charArray[2] * 10 + (int)charArray[3];
}
```

This excerpt calculate a number from a 4-element char array. From "2015" there is 55343.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Casting a `char` to an `int` yields the ASCII value of that `char` (for ASCII characters, at least), _not_ its numeric value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the purpose of the exercise is not to use `String` and `parseInt`, you need to convert the characters `'0'` to `'9'` into the digits `0` to `9`. This is done by subtracting the character `'0'`, so you get:

```
private static int getYear(char[] charArray)
{
    return (charArray[0] - '0') * 1000
         + (charArray[1] - '0') * 100
         + (charArray[2] - '0') * 10
         + (charArray[3] - '0');
}
```

---

This is because Java stores Strings in Unicode characters. Unicode is a (huge) extension of the ASCII character set.

Have a look at the ASCII printable characters on this Wikipedia page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#ASCII_printable_code_chart

As you can see, the character (glyphs) for `0` has decimal value `48`, `1` is `49`, ..., and `9` is `57`.

So, casting a `char` with the character `'0'` to an `int` will yield the value `48`. Then we rely on the fact that the characters `'0'` to `'9'` are consecutive, so subtracting 48 (the value of `'0'`) will yield `0` to `9`, which is what we want.

Comment: Just for interest: Why?

Comment: Thanks for the explaination

Answer (score 2):

```
 private static int getYear(char[] charArray)
 {
   return Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(charArray));
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private static int getYear(char[] charArray){
    return Integer.parseInt(new String(charArray));
}
```